# Does ADFS server supports scim protocol

Tags: provisioning, adfs, adfs2.0, scim

Does current Microsoft ADFS 2.0 server (or new ADFS 3.0 RTM ) support SCIM provisioning protocol ? If not which one provisioning protocol is planned SPML maybe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently none are supported.

That's because ADFS is a STS not an identity Manager.

These protocols are around provisioning not authentication.

Hence outside the ambit of ADFS.

Comment: Thanks, is then possible to send /receive SCIM messages directly against AD ?

Comment: Yes if you have some third-party software to do this. There is no built-in AD functionality.